# Find the songs and the event

Tags: riddle, logical-deduction, acrostic

The ... below refer to songs. Find them, combine them and you get a famous event currently still ongoing.

... can make all this world seem right
... like you want me
recognize your age it's a ...
... am I loud enough
Because I'm ..., I'm ... come on
This is a thing I've never known before It's called ...
... Lover of the Russian queen
Can you hear the drums ...
This crying ..., these weeping shores
I can't get no ...
'Cause this is ..., ... night

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The gaps can be filled by

> ONLY YOU / KISS ME / TEENAGE RAMPAGE / OH MY LOVE / BAD / EASY LIVIN' / RA RA RASPUTIN / FERNANDO / EARTH / SATISFACTION / THRILLER

and the event is

> OKTOBERFEST (from the first letters of the song names).

Credit where due:

> I didn't find OH MY LOVE for the fourth one (the only "Am I loud enough?" song I found was different), though of course the answer was clear without it. Thanks to Bananenkopp and ThomasL himself for setting me straight.

Comment: Have a look at rot13(Ern Tneirl - Bu zl ybir)

Comment: well done! 2nd O is from Oh My Love - Rea Garvey - could find a better one..